# List vs Map (key safety vs mapping over all elements)

Tags: data-structures, haskell

What is the best data structure for the following scenario?

Say, you have a list of URLs

```
linkHaskell = Url "http://www.haskell.org"
linkReddit = Url "http://www.reddit.com"
...
```

and you use them individually, but you also want to operate on all of them, e.g. link-check, you could put them in a list

```
allLinks = [
    linkHaskell
  , linkReddit
  ...
  ]
```

But that is error-prone, since you might forget to add a new link.

You could choose to store those URLs in a Map instead, but then you would exchange compile-time errors for runtime-errors, in case you have typos in the keys.

In Haskell what would you do?

Comment: is it possible to have a map whose keys are another data type? (for which you would provide data constructors Haskell, Reddit, and an instance of Ord) Does this lead to other problems?

Comment: Perhaps `instance Enum URL where ...` helps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple approach is to define a datatype for the links, i.e.

```
data Link = LinkHaskell | LinkReddit
    deriving (Enum, Bounded)

toUrl LinkHaskell = Url "http://www.haskell.org"
toUrl LinkReddit  = Url "http://www.reddit.org"

allLinks :: [Link]
allLinks = [minBound .. maxBound]
```

You still have to specify the name in two places, but at least now the compiler will complain if you forget to add it in one place (at least with `-Wall`).

Another approach is to use some Template Haskell magic:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Links where

import Control.Monad
import Language.Haskell.TH

data Url = Url String
    deriving (Show)

mkLinks :: [(String, String)] -> Q [Dec]
mkLinks links = liftM2 (++) mkAllLinks $ mapM mkLink links
  where
    mkLink (name, url) = valD (varP $ mkLinkName name) (normalB [| Url url |]) []
    mkAllLinks = [d| allLinks = $(listE [varE $ mkLinkName name | (name, _) <- links] )|]
    mkLinkName = mkName . ("link" ++)
```

Now you only have to specify the links in one place:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Links

mkLinks
  [("Haskell", "http://www.haskell.org")
  ,("Reddit",  "http://www.reddit.org")
  ,("StackOverflow", "http://www.stackoverflow.com")
  ]

main = do
    putStrLn "By name:"
    print $ linkHaskell
    print $ linkReddit

    putStrLn "All:"
    mapM_ print allLinks
```